# Soundcloud label music effect Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, soundcloud

I have some doubts.

Look at this
[image]

The label with the song name has a transparent background, and it fits the size of the label, breaking the label when it matters.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [attributed string](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html), and it uses: [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSBackgroundColorAttributeName)